# Changing Facebook Marketplace Location with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape Facebook marketplace from multiple locations and I'm not sure how to change my location in marketplace. I've tried the code below without any luck. What else should I try to do this?

```
params = {
    "latitude": 50.1109,
    "longitude": 8.6821,
    "accuracy": 100
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not selecting random location in Marketplace menu and select a random range?
This should change the presented groups and items.
To do so you can first open the Marketplace location dialog by clicking the element located by this `cssSelector`: `tv7at329 j83agx80 bp9cbjyn`
Now open the location drop list clicking on element located by `label[aria-label="Location"]` and randomly select one of the presented options there.
To open the radius selection click on `label[aria-label="Radius"]` element and select random option there.